Problem writing new key-value pair to file
Trying to use a translation extension for an Opencart
site, but having a problem with generating a new file.
    private function generateFileContents($translations)
    {
        $fileContents = "<?php";
        foreach ($translations as $key => $value) {
//        echo "$key: $value <br>";
        $fileContents .= "\n\$_['" . $key . '\'] = \'' . addcslashes($value, "'\\") . "';";
        }
        return $fileContents;
    }

Problem is it writes ok to the existing language file,
but the $key is missing from the translation.
The original translation remains intact, and the code
adds the new translation to the bottom of the file, like this:
$_['text_address_add'] = 'Add Address';
$_['error_zone'] = 'Please select a region / state!';
$_['error_custom_field'] = '%s required!';
$_[''] = 'Add Address test';

Any idea why the $key is getting lost, and not
overwriting the existing values?
All the other key-value pairs are in the file,
except for the key in the new translation.
Not sure if I'm showing enough code....
The code author has stopped maintaining it.

We probably need to see what you're passing into $translations

Why not use a JSON file instead of this?

The problem is almost certainly in the code that updates $translations. The code you posted writes each element the same.

So if you're getting a blank key in the file, it's because there's a blank key in the array.
